# Why smaller data set is hashed in memory for a hash join

Tags: join, hash

Why in a hash join, it is the smaller data set that is held in memory? I understand that holding the smaller set saves memory space, but it does mean that we need to iterate over the bigger data set, so is that not bad for performance?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to make a single pass over the bigger set (which you have to read at least once anyway), and multiple passes over the smaller (which is made even faster by having it in memory).